# im having problems solving this error (RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop._loop' was never awaited)

Tags: python, discord.py

this is the code. if you want any other info i can provide you with it, but as for right now this is the only place that i had hopes on. im literally stuck.

```py
import os, json
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import logging
import binance
from discord import Member
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions
from binance import Client, ThreadedWebsocketManager, ThreadedDepthCacheManager

logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename = 'discord.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(name)s:&(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)


load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
token = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
channel_id = os.getenv('CHANNEL_ID')
binance_api_key = os.getenv('BINANCE_API_KEY')
binance_api_secret = os.getenv('BINANCE_API_SECRET')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents, command_prefix='..')

binanceClient = Client(binance_api_key, binance_api_secret)

FAV_LIST = {}
with open('FAV_LIST.json') as f:
  FAV_LIST = json.load(f)

def get_future_position(symbol):
  position = None
  positions = list(filter(lambda f:(f['symbol']==symbol), binanceClient.futures_account()['positions']))
  if positions:
    position = positions[0]
  return position

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('hello'):
      await message.channel.send('Hello!')

@commands.command()
async def add_fav(ctx, account, symbol):
    FUT_SYMBOLS = [sym['symbol'] for sym in binanceClient.futures_exchange_info()['symbols']]
    SPOT_SYMBOLS = [sym['symbol'] for sym in binanceClient.get_all_tickers()]
    if account.upper() == "FUT":
        if symbol in FUT_SYMBOLS:
            FAV_LIST['FUTURES'][symbol] = {}
        else:
            await ctx.send("Provided SYMBOL or CRYPTO is not available in Futures")
    elif account.upper() == "SPOT":
        if symbol in SPOT_SYMBOLS:
            FAV_LIST['SPOT'][symbol] = {}
        else:
            await ctx.send("Provided SYMBOL or CRYPTO is not available in SPOT")
    else:
        await ctx.send('Provided Account Type is not valid. Please use FUT for Futures and SPOT for spot')
    with open('FAV_LIST.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(FAV_LIST, f)


@commands.command()
async def favs(ctx):
    message = "FUTURES FAVOURITE LIST\n"
    for i, symbol in enumerate(FAV_LIST['FUTURES'].keys()):
        message += str(i+1) + ". " + symbol + "--> Last Price: "+ binanceClient.get_ticker(symbol=symbol)['lastPrice']+"\n"
    message += "\n\nSPOT FAVOURITE LIST"
    for i, symbol in enumerate(FAV_LIST['SPOT'].keys()):
        message += str(i+1) + ". " + symbol + "--> Last Price: "+ binanceClient.get_ticker(symbol=symbol)['lastPrice']+ "\n"
    await ctx.send(message)
    
@commands.command()
async def fubln(ctx):
    balance_list = binanceClient.futures_account_balance()
    message = "-"*35 + "\n"
    message += "-"*3 + "ACCOUNT BALANCE" + "-"*3 + "\n"
    message += "-"*35 +"\n"
    for balance in balance_list:
        message += balance['asset']+" : "+balance['balance']+"\n"
    message += "-"*35
    await ctx.send(message)

@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def futures_position_alerts():
    futures_info = binanceClient.futures_account()
    positions_info = binanceClient.futures_position_information()
    positions = futures_info['positions']
    message_channel = await client.fetch_channel(channel_id)
    print(f"Got channel {message_channel} for {channel_id}")
    if float(futures_info['totalMaintMargin'])/float(futures_info['totalMarginBalance']) > 40.0:
        await message_channel.send("Your positions' Margin Ratio is greater than 40%. Please consider taking a look at it.")
    for position in positions:
        symbol = position['symbol']
        alert = False
        message = "------"+symbol+" POSITION ALERT!------\n"
        position_info = list(filter(lambda f:(f['symbol']==symbol),positions_info))[0]
        if float(position_info['positionAmt']) != 0.0:
            if float(position['unrealizedProfit']) < -1.0 :
                message += "Unrealized Profit is going down! LOSS : "+ str(position['unrealizedProfit']) +"\n"
                alert = True
            if (float(position_info['markPrice'])-float(position_info['liquidationPrice']))/(float(position_info['entryPrice'])-float(position_info['liquidationPrice'])) <= 0.4:
                message += "Mark price is moving closer to Liquidation Price. Your position may be liquidated soon.\n Mark Price:"+ str(position_info['markPrice']) +"\n Liquidation Price:"+str(position_info['liquidationPrice'])+"\n"
                alert = True
        if alert:
            await message_channel.send(message)

@futures_position_alerts.before_loop
async def before():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")

futures_position_alerts.start()

#@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
#async def favs_info():
#    message = "INFO of Favourite Crytos\n\n"
#    message += "FUTURES\n"
#    for i, symbol in enumerate(FAV_LIST['FUTURES'].keys()):
#        position = get_future_position(symbol)
#        message += str(i)+". "+position['symbol']+" --> unrealizedProfit : "+position['unrealizedProfit']
#    message_channel = await client.fetch_channel(channel_id)
#    print(f"Got channel {message_channel} for {channel_id}")
#    await message_channel.send(message)

#@favs_info.before_loop
#async def before():
#    await client.wait_until_ready()
#    print("Finished waiting")

#favs_info.start()

# MODERATION COMMANDS #        
@commands.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True, administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, member:discord.Member,*,reason=None):
  guild = ctx.guild
  memberKick = discord.Embed(title='Kicked', description = f'You have been kicked from {guild.name} for {reason}')
  
  await member.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been kicked.')
  
@commands.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members=True, administrator=True)
async def ban(ctx, member:discord.Member,*,reason=None,):
  guild = ctx.guild
  memberBan = discord.Embed(title = 'Banned', description=f'You were banned from {guild.name} for {reason}')
  
  await member.ban(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been banned.')
  await member.send(embed=memberBan)
  
@commands.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members=True, administrator=True)
async def unban(self, ctx, *, member:discord.Member):
  banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
  member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')
  
  for ban_entry in banned_users:
    user = ban_entry.user
    
    if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
      await ctx.guild.unban(user)
      await ctx.send(f'{user.name}#{user.discriminator} has been unbanned.')
      return

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx,member:discord.Member, reason = None):
  guild = ctx.guild
  mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Muted')
  memberMute = discord.Embed(title = 'Muted', description=f'You have been muted from {guild.name} for {reason}')
  if mutedRole not in guild.roles:
    perms = discord.Permissions(send_messages=False, speak=False)
    await guild.create_role(name='Muted', permissions=perms)
    await member.add_roles(mutedRole)
    await ctx.send('Succesfuly created the [Muted] role and properly assigned it to the user.')
  await ctx.add_role(member, mutedRole)
  embed=discord.Embed(title='User muted!', description=f'**{0}** was muted by **{1}**!'.format(member, ctx.message.author, color=0xff00f6))
  
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def unmute(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  guild = ctx.guild
  mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'Muted')
  
  memberUnmute = discord.Embed(title = 'Unmuted', description = f'You were unmuted from {guild.name} for {reason}')
  
  await member.remove_roles(mutedRole)
  await ctx.send(f'Unmuted {member.mention} for {reason}')
  await member.send(embed=memberUnmute)

client.run(token)
```

```
#TRACEBACK#
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\arlit\Desktop\iceC-main\main.py", line 122, in <module>
    futures_position_alerts.start()
  File "C:\Users\arlit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 398, in start
    self._task = asyncio.create_task(self._loop(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\arlit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 336, in create_task
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop._loop' was never awaited
```

well i tried closing the loop but i didnt get it to work exactly how i wanted it to.
Edit: this is the whole code and the traceback below it. since it was too short. now ill have to add some random text since stack doesnt let me post too much code without adding some words.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the code where you define your client and where you run your client. Additionally, having the full error traceback would be more useful rather than a snippet in the title.

Comment: sure @ESloman lemme do that

Comment: What version of `discord.py` are you on?

Comment: @ESloman discord.py-2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `futures_position_alerts.start()` at the top level of your file. As the error message is telling you, you have to call it in an async context. There's an [official example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py#L15) that you could look at.